# A program to mutate Nested Lists

Tags: python

Could someone help me do two things:

1. Review the code and see if it could be written in a better way.
2. Finish this program. I got stuck in trying to put the list back the way it is. i.e. a nested list of lists.

Here we go:

```
t = ['a', 'b', ['c', 'd'], ['e'], 'f']

def capitalize_list(t):
    L = []
    N = []
    for i in range(len(t)):
        if type(t[i]) == str:
            L.append(t[i].capitalize())
        if type(t[i]) == list:
            L.extend(t[i])
            for s in L:
                N.append(s.capitalize())
     print N 

 capitalize_list(t)
```

This code prints:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

I need it to print:

```
['A', 'B', ['C', 'D'], ['E'], 'F']
```

Comment: Do you understand what `list.extend()` does?

Comment: yes sir. You basically add the elements of a list to a list without the brackets.

Comment: Delnan, thank you for fixing my post. I was in the process of doing so. must have forgotten a space or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
def capitalize_list(t):
    N = []
    for i in range(len(t)):
        if type(t[i]) == str:
            N.append(t[i].capitalize())
        if type(t[i]) == list:
            N.append(capitalize_list(t[i]))
    return N
```

*Output:*

```
['A', 'B', ['C', 'D'], ['E'], 'F']
```

Comment: I guess list.append() would work for both objects and lists. When I read about it it only mentioned items within a list hence my confusion.

Comment: @Quester: A list is just another type of object.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of doing this recursively:

```
def capitalize(item):
    if type(item) is str:
        return item.capitalize()
    if type(item) is list:
        return map(capitalize, item)
```

You could even do

```
def capitalize(item):
    try:
        return item.capitalize()
    except AttributeError:
        return map(capitalize, item)
```

-- which would use the capitalize method for any object that has it (such as a normal or unicode string) and attempt to iterate through any object that does not.